# FORTRAN: Segmentation fault while passing real = real(:,:)

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran90, optional-parameters

I'm doing a program which calculate the scalar product between 2 arrays. The result is a scalar real value. My solution is to use an matrix which dimension is (1,1). No problem with this, but just adding the line

```
res=tmp_2(1,1)
```

i got the segmentation fault.
The code is:

```
call product(u, v, m0, 3, res)

print*, "The result is ", res

call product(u, u, m0, 3, umod)

umod=sqrt(umod)

call product(v, v, m0, 3, vmod)

vmod=sqrt(vmod)

angle=acos(res/(umod*vmod))

print*, "The angle is: ", angle

contains

subroutine product(v, u, metr, n, res)

real, dimension(:,:), intent(in)        ::  metr
real, dimension(:), intent(in)          ::  u, v
integer, intent(in)                     ::  n

real, optional, intent(out)             ::  res

real, dimension(:,:), allocatable       ::  v_t, tmp, tmp_1, tmp_2
integer                                 ::  i, j

allocate(tmp(n,1))
allocate(tmp_1(n,1))
allocate(tmp_2(1,1))
allocate(v_t(1,n))

call vec_mat(v, tmp, n)          !convert vector(n) to matrix(n,1) to be able to
                                 !operate with my multiplication subroutine
call vec_mat(u, tmp_1, n)

call mattrans(tmp, n, 1, v_t)    !matrix transposition

deallocate(tmp)
allocate(tmp(1,n))

call matmul(v_t, metr, 1, n, n, tmp)     !matrixes moltiplication

call matmul(tmp, tmp_1, 1, n, 1, tmp_2)

res=tmp_2(1,1)    !!!!!!!!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!             <---------------

end subroutine product
```

All the subroutines called are in a module, but everything's tested and works.

P.S. My server is spanish so the actual error is "Violacion de segmento ('core' generado)" which i suppose to be the Segmentation Fault.

Comment: is `res `actally present?

Comment: do you mean if i declared it? yes, i did.

Comment: No, it is an optional argument. It must be present in the argument list.

Comment: yes. 'subroutine product(v, u, metr, n, res)' is the declaration of the function and its call 'call product(u, v, m0, 3, res)'.

Comment: And how is res declared in this call?

Comment: Segentation Fault is a memory problem. You should not focus exclusively on the line you add (res) to create the error. Consider also that the problem can come from what happens before. I would suggest you to check what happens inside the matmul calls just before. Also, Valgrind may help you to find the problem.

Comment: Compile with all the debugging checks available, for gfortran try `-fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never invoke an optional argument without testing that it is PRESENT, so the problematic line of code should be changed to

```
if (present(res)) res = tmp_2(1,1)
```

When this change is made, does the problem still occur?

Comment: That solved the problem! It was the first time using a optional argument so I didn't know about the control! Thanks a lot!